# Template alternative for macros

Tags: templates, macros

I want to implement a macro like below

```cpp
#define LogDebug(x) #ifdef _DEBUG #x #endif
```

But due to limitation of macros, above code was not possible. So what could be a template alternative for the above macro?

Comment: This macro doesn't *do* anything. It expands to either a string literal or nothing. What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: I was planing on printing some values if it is in debug mode, so that I could call like
LogDebug(std::cout << some_value << std::endl)

Comment: This would expand to `"std::cout << some_value << std::endl"` (note the quotation marks). I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, so that it will print for debug mode but not for release mode.